# Every request to be routed to a single controller - MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I was asked this question in an interview.
Can someone please let me know the answer for this.

"I have an MVC application and I want all the requests to be targeted to a single controller, which would then decide the actual controller to which the request to be sent to and that controller should actually handle the request. How do I achieve this?"

Thanks,
Vijendra

Comment: Create a `BaseController` which will be inherited by all other controller. I would suggest you to do some research before posting a question, because in SO this question can be considered as off topic.

Comment: I am not looking for a BaseController sir, I am looking for a route which would redirect all the requests to that controller. I wish you understand the question a bit more.

Comment: In your question test, I never saw a word `Route`, except in title. I gave the comment based on question text.

Comment: you need to handle in ``RouteConfig.cs`` file for every route you can hard-code some specific controller

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bad idea, but if you wanted to do something like that you would do it like this in `RouteConfig.cs`

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { 
                    controller = "Base", 
                    action = "Index", 
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

And you would have a matching `BaseController.cs`